# How can I eliminate certain values (zeros) and get the maximum value from some data group?

Tags: c#

I'm newbie in C#. My problem is, I have 19 double values. Some of them are equals to zero. I want to eliminate these zeros and find the maximum one from remaining values. How can i do that ? My code includes only double values.

```
double m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12, m13, m14, m15, m16, m17, m18, m19;

        m1 = 200;
        m2 = 1000;
        m3 = 1500;
        m4 = 2000;
        m5 = 4000;
        m6 = 7000;
        m7 = 10000;
        m8 = 12000;
        m9 = 14000;
        m10 = 16000;
        m11 = 0;
        m12 = 0;
        m13 = 0;
        m14 = 0;
```

Comment: They would be easier to work with if they were in a collection (like `List<double>`)

Comment: Why do you care about the zeros anyway when you're looking for the maximum value? Unless they can be negative too, but then 0 is larger than -1.

Comment: What do you mean with "eliminate"?

Comment: sorry guys, i did not think correct, i only need the maximum value. the reason i did not use a list is these values come from an access database.

Comment: reason of using zeros are in my database, these 19 values belongs to seperate things. some of them have 11 values but the maximum is 19. so i used zero (because i don't know the null operation in access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using individual variables for each value makes the task very tedious because you must write code for every one of these variables. Insert the values into a collection.

If you have a fixed set of values (e.g., always 19 values), you can use an array. If you have a varying number of values use a list. I will be using a list because this is  a more universal approach.

```cs
var m = new List<double> {
 200, 1000, 1500, 2000, 4000,  7000, 10000, 12000, 14000, 16000, 0,  0, 0, 0
};
```

Now you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to process the values

```cs
double maximumValue = m
    .Where(x => x != 0)
    .Max();
```

The `Where` extension method filters the values. `x =>` introduces a variable to which each value will be assigned in turn. `x != 0` is the condition which will applied to each of these values. Only the ones where the condition is fulfilled pass through the filter and are given over to the next stage, which is the `Max` extension method returning the maximum value.

Note that the filter will only have an effect if you have only negative values and zeroes resulting in a negative maximum value. Because if the maximum is positive, the zeroes will not affect the result.

If you know that the maximum value will be a positive value, then you can simply write

```cs
double maximumValue = m.Max();
```

Comment: Of course you can but there are numerous possible of solutions for this, depending on the database type (Oracle, SQL-Server, MySQL, SQLite, XML, Json etc.) and the data access technology (EF, EF-Core, ADO.NET, Dapper etc.). Ask a new question for this and give (much) more details. Also, for data coming from the DB you would apply the MAX function on the DB side and not in the C# code.